# Error in rounded-list counter?

Tags: html, css, counter

Creating a counter for webpage is easy but its difficult to implement and match the CSS & HTML in exact position. However I've created a rounded list counter for ol and li tags. Overall it works with showing colors, hover effects and other designing but It only shows 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 and so on in each line..

```css
            .rounded-list li{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
    *padding: .4em;
    margin: .5em 0;
    background: #ddd;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    -moz-border-radius: .3em;
    -webkit-border-radius: .3em;
    border-radius: .3em;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out; 
   }

   .rounded-list li:hover{
    background: #eee;
   }

   .rounded-list li:hover:before{
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
       -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
       -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
       transform: rotate(360deg); 
   }

   .rounded-list li:before{
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
    position: absolute; 
    left: -1.3em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1.3em;
    background: #eee;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    border: .3em solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    -moz-border-radius: 2em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
   }
```

```html
<ol class="rounded-list">
<li>Sample text 1</li>
<li>Sample text 2</li>
<li>Sample text 3</li>
<li>Sample text 4</li>
<li>Sample text 5</li>
<li>Sample text 6</li>
<li>Sample text 7</li>
<li>Sample text 8</li>
<li>Sample text 9</li>
<li>Sample text 10</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset a counter first. So i added the `.rounded-list{counter-reset:li;}`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters

```css
.rounded-list{counter-reset:li;}
.rounded-list li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
  *padding: .4em;
  margin: .5em 0;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-border-radius: .3em;
  -webkit-border-radius: .3em;
  border-radius: .3em;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
.rounded-list li:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
.rounded-list li:hover:before {
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
.rounded-list li:before {
  counter-increment: li;
  content: counter(li);
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.3em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.3em;
  background: #eee;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border: .3em solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  -moz-border-radius: 2em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<ol class="rounded-list">
  <li>Sample text 1</li>
  <li>Sample text 2</li>
  <li>Sample text 3</li>
  <li>Sample text 4</li>
  <li>Sample text 5</li>
  <li>Sample text 6</li>
  <li>Sample text 7</li>
  <li>Sample text 8</li>
  <li>Sample text 9</li>
  <li>Sample text 10</li>
</ol>
```